# Mac contextual menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm developing a Mac application for sharing files to different social platforms like Flickr, Facebook etc. I want to add the 'share with MyApp' facility within the contextual menu of the files. i.e, when i (control+click) any file in the file system, i must see a menu item like 'share with MyApp' in the contextual menu so that i can run my application for sharing the files.This is the requirement and my question is : is it possible to do and if possible, how this can be achieved? My application will be compatible with OS 10.6 and higher version. I know that there is a facility like Open with > my application name.But i want to show it directly in the contextual menu.

Thanks,
LS Developer

Comment: As mentioned by @Yan it would probably be best to make 'MAC' lowercase to avoid confusion with Media Access Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Mac isn't an acronym.

Secondly, you can't add directly to Finder's contextual menu, that is far outside Apple's HIG. What you *can* do however, is add a Service that enables the share facility (Services are accessible from the context menu). You can find more information about OS X services here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MakingAppServices

Comment: I've seen some applications like CloudApp, Courier (www.realmacsoftware.com/courier/ ), have the same feature that I'm talking.Can I presume they also works as services?

Comment: Have you been able to add a Service in the contextual menu ? I am following the cocoadev example (and even Apple's docu), but no service is displayed...